# Header and data elements in same row using set_template in CodeIgniter

Tags: html, codeigniter

I am using the [HTML Table Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/table.html) of CodeIgniter, and attempting to create a table template.  The example given in the documentation is the following:

```
$tmpl = array (
                'table_open'          => '<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">',

                'heading_row_start'   => '<tr>',
                'heading_row_end'     => '</tr>',
                'heading_cell_start'  => '<th>',
                'heading_cell_end'    => '</th>',

                'row_start'           => '<tr>',
                'row_end'             => '</tr>',
                'cell_start'          => '<td>',
                'cell_end'            => '</td>',

                'row_alt_start'       => '<tr>',
                'row_alt_end'         => '</tr>',
                'cell_alt_start'      => '<td>',
                'cell_alt_end'        => '</td>',

                'table_close'         => '</table>'
          );

$this->table->set_template($tmpl);
```

When I apply this template to my query, this is the resulting HTML:

```
<table data-hide-table="false" data-orientation="vertical" class="chart">
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th><th>Rate per SF</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>2008</td><td>48</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>2009</td><td>32</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>2010</td><td>32</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>2011</td><td>32</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>2012</td><td>40</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>2013</td><td>41</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The problem with this example is that each row contains two data elements (`<td></td><td></td>`), instead of one header element and one data element (`<th></th><td></td>`).

How can I change the template so that my resulting table will have one header element and one data element (`<th></th><td></td>`) on each row like this:

```
<table data-hide-table="false" data-orientation="vertical" class="chart">
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th><th>Rate per SF</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>2008</th><td>48</td></tr>
<tr>
<th>2009</th><td>32</td></tr>
<tr>
<th>2010</th><td>32</td></tr>
<tr>
<th>2011</th><td>32</td></tr>
<tr>
<th>2012</th><td>40</td></tr>
<tr>
<th>2013</th><td>41</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no you can't change template like this but yes you can somewhere achieve this kind of functionality

If you see the http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/table.html there is a option to add a callable function so I suggest you are creating a table make some flag if you are using that table is generating than create a helper function and add that to the table function than before generating table set a flag to determine the first cell may be using cookie. Than from helper for every 1, 3....(2n+1) add some custom html tag or style. Than after generating the table remove all the flags.